# Oracle sql table variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 the same databases and I would like to update data from first to second database.

1. Is there possible to declare table as variable?
2. Is there way to go throught whole database and update every table from first to second database?

I am trying this code:

```
DECLARE
   tab table;
BEGIN
   tab := simpacks_types;

delete from TECH.tab;
insert into TECH.tab select * from ra012345.tab;
```

Thank you

Comment: With dynamic SQL only, because identifiers (object names) are processed and validated at parse time, when external data (variables' values) is not accessed. Also note that in SQL world column permutations are generally considered to be equal because columns are accessed by names. This breaks easy `select *` approach when doing inserts because target table may have the same columns but in different order

Comment: Did you consider using **Data Pump** export and import utilities to move tables (and data stored within) around?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a dynamic SQL approach here to get your desired result -

```
DECLARE
   tab VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   tab := 'Table_name';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from TECH.' || tab;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into TECH.' || tab || ' select * from ra012345.' || tab;
END;
```

If you have list of tables which needs to be loaded one after another you may try using a cursor for that.